# Cassandra Error saving keyspace and doesn't display keyspaces in opscenter

Tags: java, cassandra

if i try to save a new key space its giving me the following error.

```
Error saving keyspace: Call to /Cluster/keyspaces/newname timed out.
```

if i want to create an existing keyspace , i get the following error

```
Error saving keyspace: Keyspace names must be case-insensitively unique ("shashank" conflicts with "shashank")
```

The problem is I cannot see any keyspace in my opscenter user interface browser

Answer (score 0):

One really easy way to see your existing keyspaces is to open up the CQL shell on one of your nodes.  Go to the bin folder under the root folder where Cassandra was installed, and run "CQLSH".  From this command prompt, you can simply type "describe keyspaces" and you will get a listing of all of the available keyspaces in this cluster.

One thing to note is that case sensitivity is only observed by Cassandra if you put double quotes around the name of an object.  Otherwise everything just gets converted to lower case and compared that way.